# Ansible disable repo not functioning as expected

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, redhat

I've tried this with two different modules, however I always get status returned: "OK", rather than the expected "Changed". Checking the Server also shows that no changes have been made and the repo is still active:

```
- hosts: rh_estate
  user: whatuser
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Disable YUM Repo
      yum_repository:
        name: rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms
        state: absent
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat"
```

And with the Yum Module:

```
- name: Disable YUM Repo
  yum:
    disablerepo: rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms
  when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat"
```

I would rather use modules than Line in file. I suppose if there is actually no other way, I would prefer the shell `yum-config-manager --disable rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms`

Repo Declaration:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/rh-cloud.repo
[rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras from RHUI (Debug RPMs)
baseurl=https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/debug
        https://rhui-2.microsoft.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/debug
        https://rhui-3.microsoft.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/debug
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify=1
sslclientcert=/etc/pki/rhui/product/content.crt
sslclientkey=/etc/pki/rhui/key.pem
```

Output of yum repolist all:

```
[root@server ~]# yum repolist all | grep 'repo id\|rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras'
repo id                                                           status
rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms/x86_64                  enabled:    262
rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-rpms/x86_64                        enabled:  1,105
rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-source-rpms/x86_64                 enabled:    430
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the related repo declaration as well as the filename in which that declaration is stored ?

Comment: @Zeitounator - could you ellaborate on `related repo declaration` please? The `repo name` provided is the `repo id` found on the destination hosts. Do I need to declare it as a `var` first and use the `var ref` as `repo name`?

Comment: I mean the full repo declaration with its ini section header and all its declared option as it is currently set on your server in /etc/yum.repos.d/somefile

Comment: @Zeitounator added - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the extra info to test correctly. Have a look at the [`yum_repository` module doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) and the `file` parameter which states:

> File name without the .repo extension to save the repo in. Defaults to the value of name.

In your case, the filename holding your repository is different from the uid (aka name in Ansible context) of your repo. You need to provide the file parameter as requested for your task to complete:

```yaml
    - name: Disable YUM Repo
      yum_repository:
        name: rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms
        file: rh-cloud
        state: absent
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat"
```

Quickly tested (without condition) against a centos:7 docker container.

You have several other helpfull example at the bottom of the documentation page.

Note: using `disable_repo` with the [`yum` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) will only temporarily disable specific repo(s) for a single yum operation, not remove it completely from the configuration. From documentation:

> These repos will not persist beyond the transaction.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. What doesn't though - is ansible was aware that the repo existed - it didn't error out. Why then was it specifically important to add the filename - compared to bash's equivalent of `yum-config-manager --disable rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-debug-rpms`? I appreciate if I'm adding repos this would be a mandatory field, just not when I'm enabling/disabling them.

Comment: Disable with yum-config-manager is different from what we have juste done. In my answer we totally removed the repo definition (you cannot use it anymore at all). In your command case, you simple add `enable=0` in the config. You can acheive this as well with the module in ansible, just set the corresponding parameters.

Comment: So to simply disable (but keep the config) instead of `state: absent` I'm calling `enabled: No`?

Comment: You got it. You may have to set some other params as well. Just give it a try and see the result.